# PHPStorm - Class Oauth Not Found During Runtime

Tags: php, oauth, phpstorm

I'm trying to call new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret); 
I could see it working from the browser. However when I try to run it from PHPStorm I am getting runtime error "class OAuth not found" 
In the editor it shows the declaration properly taking to oauth.php file. 
Could not figure out why the problem occurs only during runtime.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.
phpstorm was using php.ini under mamp/bin folder and the php_oauth.dll extension was not updated there.